# Documentation information blurb has random END OF TEXT control characters in it

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

The big blue box that describes what Documentation is (easily visible on [any proposed tag](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/abstract-class)) has extraneous control characters interjected into the middle of the lines. Running the lines through a character identification tool reveals that these are U+0003 END OF TEXT characters (commonly occurring from doing a Control-C in command line).

Normally, not a big deal, until you run across a browser that actually attempts to render these characters, which results in the ugly empty box character to appear instead:

[image: Control Characters!]

Seems like an easy fix to just delete the characters out of the text, even if it doesn't occur in many major browsers. There's no reason for them to be there, and would probably even break any command-line browsers attempting to load the page.

Comment: Sense your a moderator, can't you sort of....fix stuff like this _yourself_? No offense.

Comment: @leaf moderators can't fix these, Only employees can.....  But errm, animuson is an employee, So yeah, only devs can fix :D

Comment: Still, seems weird to me to post something like this on meta rather than through employee chanels

Comment: @SGR animuson is just hunting for a hat....

Comment: well maybe it's just to make a reference post to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @SGR: Why? This is where bugs get reported. Who cares who's reporting it?

Comment: I think the source of the problem is more interesting then the problem itself. They shouldn't be there in the first place and remonving them only solves this instance , there may be more

Comment: Looks like SO should set up Bugzilla or something internally so that we don't need to misuse Meta for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've cleaned these up. It looks like this was a one-time mistake that hasn't been repeated, and these characters aren't found anywhere else in our templates, so you shouldn't see this again.